# Android Seekbar stops updating on orientation change

Tags: android, event-handling, seekbar

I have a mediaplayer seekbar which is working fine until I rotate the screen. What I would like to see is the seekbar progress continue. However it resets to zero and no longer responds to touch event.

This is code in oncreate:

```
mSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            seekChange(v);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And in main class:

```
private final Runnable updatePositionRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updatePosition();
    }
};
private void updatePosition() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
    try{
        if (mp != null) mSeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(0);
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
    }
    handler.postDelayed(updatePositionRunnable, 100);
}


//seekbar re-position track
private void seekChange(View v) {
    try{
        if (mp != null) mp.seekTo(mSeekBar.getProgress());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by myself in the end:

Add

> android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

to the Manifest for each activity you need to update.